Aiogram how to catch network exceptions?
Periodically, I see errors like ConnectionResetError: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host in the logs. However, they are not blocking, and the bot continues further work, but I don’t understand how to catch them? If you wrap the Dispatcher().start_polling() method in a try-except, it does not catch them, since this happens (as I understand it) somewhere inside the aiohttp. These errors do not essentially interfere with work, but I would like to put things in order in the log files and in the sentry work, since these tracebacks greatly clutter up the logs
